# Internet Explorer 6 emulator recommendation

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-6, emulation

What good tool can be recommended for emulating Internet Explorer 6?  I would rather not have to go and install an old copy of Windows XP somewhere.

Comment: Commiserations to the person that just upvoted this, 7 years later, who is obviously *still* supporting IE6...

Comment: And also to the person that just upvoted this 14 years later...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Microsoft offer a number of Virtual PC images with various versions of IE for download.](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)

They now also offer [VMs to run VirtualBox, VMware and Parallels on Windows, OSX and Linux.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Comment: Cheers.  That's a pretty massive download...  Might have to wait until tonight.

Comment: I would also recommend this. Nothing can be more like IE6 than IE6 :) Only downside is the timelimit on these images. If you're running Windows 7 you can just create a virtual Pc of XP and install IE6 and run it from your desktop

Comment: I agree to recommend this, but from time to time I come to think that the IE6 image with approx. 600MB will be for a very long time by far the largest browser binary available (perhaps only topped by the IE7 download from the same page)...

Comment: Both links don't work anymore, the first one redirect to a generic site and the second an Edge download page.

Answer (score 7):

http://spoon.net/browsers/  Spoon lets you create web-hosted versions of your existing Windows apps that run instantly from your web site, with no install.  Spoon has a gallery of browsers that you may launch including:

Microsoft Internet Explorer 8, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 6
Mozilla Firefox 3.5, Firefox 3 and Firefox 2
Apple Safari 4 and Safari 3
Google Chrome, Opera 10, Opera 9

Comment: I used to use this, but it looks like IE emulation doesn't work the same anymore.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior What do you mean with it doesn't work the same anymore?

Comment: @williamcarswell: Go to the URL. It says "(Internet Explorer is not available in the library by request of the publisher.)"

Answer (score 5):

[Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) (which is now part of [Microsoft Expression Web 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web#Microsoft_Expression_Web_3)) has the capability to show you how a page would render in Internet Explorer 6, it also has some nice features to overlay an Internet Explorer 7 render or an image so you can see where those 1 pixel discrepancies are occuring.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a Windows OS, you can install MultipleIE.  It will allow you to run IE6 as a standalone.

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Not sure what your OS is though.

Comment: Just like to point out on Vista, this causes IE6 to be recognised as IE, so you'll end up testing how your IE7 styles work in IE6, and not how your IE6 styles work.

Comment: Great installation, been using it for a year or so now for XP and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

[Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) lets you test your site in dozens of different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I found recently that you can do this quite nicely in Windows 7, using the Windows XP mode. You need two virtual hard drives set up, but you can then create shortcuts on your Windows 7 desktop to 'open' Internet Explorer 6. There's a good walkthrough of how to do this here:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ie6-ie7-ie8-win7-xp-mode/1

Answer (score 2):

[netrenderer](http://netrenderer.com/) is a

- free,
- very quick (no wait times at all),
- platform independent, and
- versatile (IE5.5--IE10)

solution that does not require any local installations. My definite choice after trying out more than a handful of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

https://browserlab.adobe.com/ gives you an image of your site in various browsers. Not a real world experience but handy nonetheless.

Edit: On March 13, 2013 BrowserLab was shut down.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 you can download [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx), which gets you a fully-licensed version of XP. It [integrates nicely](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2009/06/24/using-windows-7s-xp-mode-to-run-ie-6-and-ie-7-side-by-side/) with windows 7, and it never expires like the free VPC images.

Answer (score 0):

People generally use VMWare, or another virtualisation tool, to do this. At least where I work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Linux box I think that IE4Linux is IE6.